# How to allocate drives with SLURM

Tags: linux, plugins, disk, slurm

I need to share drives (*SSDs* or *hard drives*) in a compute node. The Generic Resource ([GRES](http://slurm.schedmd.com/gres.html)) Scheduling is a **Slurm** module designed to manage different kind of resources. For instance it gets a plugin for GPU allocation management. I'd like to use *GRES* to handle a few drives in a shared compute nodes (and get exclusive access to a subset of these drives).

Here is my attempt (I'm using slurm *15.08.10*).

**/etc/slurm/slurm.conf** (on the head node and compute node):

```
...
GresTypes=drive

NodeName=cnode01           NodeHostname=cnode01   Gres=drive:5
...
```

**/etc/slurm/gres.conf** (on the compute node):

```
Name=drive File=/dev/sg0
Name=drive File=/dev/sg1
Name=drive File=/dev/sg2
Name=drive File=/dev/sg3
```

After having restarted *slurm daemon* on the head and compute nodes, ressource allocation is now possible (**Gres=drive:4** appears in node description):

```
> scontrol show node cnode01
  NodeName=cnode01 Arch=x86_64 CoresPerSocket=8
     CPUAlloc=0 CPUErr=0 CPUTot=32 CPULoad=1.62
     Gres=drive:4
     NodeAddr=cnode01 NodeHostName=cnode01 Version=15.08
     OS=Linux RealMemory=257469 AllocMem=0 FreeMem=231417 Sockets=2 Boards=1
     State=IDLE ThreadsPerCore=2 TmpDisk=442475 Weight=1 Owner=N/A
     BootTime=2016-04-25T11:08:10 SlurmdStartTime=2016-04-27T11:01:35
     CapWatts=n/a
     CurrentWatts=0 LowestJoules=0 ConsumedJoules=0
     ExtSensorsJoules=n/s ExtSensorsWatts=0 ExtSensorsTemp=n/s
```

But when drives are allocate, there is no specific environment variable set:

```
> salloc -w cnode01 --gres=drive:2 --share
> env
  ...
  SLURM_NODELIST=cnode01
  SLURMD_NODENAME=cnode01
  SLURM_TOPOLOGY_ADDR=cnode01
  SLURM_PRIO_PROCESS=0
  SLURM_SRUN_COMM_PORT=52028
  SLURM_TOPOLOGY_ADDR_PATTERN=no
  SLURM_NNODES=1
  SLURM_STEP_NUM_NODES=1
  SLURM_JOBID=42
  SLURM_NTASKS=1
  SLURM_STEP_ID=0
  SLURM_STEP_LAUNCHER_PORT=52028
  SLURM_TASKS_PER_NODE=1
  SLURM_JOB_ID=42
  SLURM_STEPID=0
  SLURM_NODEID=0
  SLURM_TASK_PID=19131
  SLURM_NPROCS=1
  SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE=32
  SLURM_DISTRIBUTION=cyclic
  SLURM_PROCID=0
  SLURM_JOB_NODELIST=cnode01
  SLURM_LOCALID=0
  SLURM_GTIDS=0
  SLURM_STEP_NUM_TASKS=1
  SLURM_JOB_NUM_NODES=1
  SLURM_STEP_TASKS_PER_NODE=1
  SLURM_STEP_NODELIST=cnode01
```

and all devices are still visible:

```
> ssh cnode01 "ls /dev/sg*"
  /dev/sg0
  /dev/sg1
  /dev/sg2
  /dev/sg3
```

Do I need to prepare a specific *plugin* in order to export a list of the reserved devices in an environment variable and/or be able to hide unreserved devices? How to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not complitelly sure that my answer can help you after so many years but. It seems that GRES oriented only for specific devices that supported by specific plugins/utilites that provide some status for theese resource.
So, only GPU (NVIDIA, AMD) and oneAPI. Unfortunatelly that's all.

Have the same problem too. Needs to add some resource to SLURM.